# can i upload gae-data to localhost server 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, upload, localhost

this is my Teackback:

```
D:\zjm_demo\app>appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --filename=upload/a.csv --kind=College --url=http://localhost:8100/remote_api
Uploading data records.
app_id argument required for non appspot.com domains

D:\zjm_demo\app>appcfg.py upload_data --app_id=zjm1126 --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --filename=upload/a.csv --kind=College --url=http://localhost:8100/rem
ote_api
Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>

appcfg.py: error: no such option: --app_id

D:\zjm_demo\app>appcfg.py upload_data app_id=zjm1126 --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --filename=upload/a.csv --kind=College --url=http://localhost:8100/remot
e_api
Usage: appcfg.py [options] upload_data <directory>

appcfg.py: error: Not a directory: app_id=zjm1126
```

can i upload data to localhost server .

thanks

**updated**

my ste_loader.py is :

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
# 以下是 Model 的 Definition
class College(db.Model):
    cid = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

# 以下是匯入資料的 class
class CollegeLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'College',
                                   [
                                    ('cid', str),
                                    ('name', lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf-8')),
                                   ])

loaders = [CollegeLoader]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument for upload_data is --application or -A, not --app_id:

```
upload_data --application=zjm1126 --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --filename=upload/a.csv --kind=College --url=http://localhost:8100/rem
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I'm trying to do this myself and thought I should leave a note for future travellers.

Yes: You can upload data to the dev server running on local host. The ste_loader.py file in the original question is a deprecated way of doing this. The preferred way is to write a .yaml file to describe the transforms. I found useful information to help me understand that [here](http://aleatory.clientsideweb.net/2012/08/20/financial-charts-app-engine-tutorial-bulkloading-data/), and [here (but be careful I think this is outdated)](http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/). The official docs are here: [GAE Documentation for appcfg.py and bulkloader.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata), but unfortunately I didn't find it very helpful. I eventually resorted to reading the source here: [source for google.appengine.ext.bulkload.transform.py](https://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py&q=bulkload%201%20file%3a%5Etrunk/python/google/appengine/&type=cs).

Answer (score 0):

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://APPNAME.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=dump --kind=EntityName
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=dump --application=dev~APPNAME
```

If you have problems with the authentication, put the following in your appengine_config.py:

```
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development'):
    remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = (
    'REMOTE_ADDR', ['127.0.0.1'])
```